# How can i load .js file in html with button

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I would like to load a javascript file in an html document.
I need to do it with a bbutton.
I have two files the "index.html" and "testing.js"
i have to load the whole of the js file.
how could this be possible?

Comment: would you please elaborate?.. im having trouble understanding the context of your question.  why wouldnt you load the js file normally using a script tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have jQuery loaded in your page, just write the following line:

```
  $.getScript("testing.js");
```

Otherwise you need to add a script tag as below:

```
var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
scriptTag.setAttribute('src','testing.js');
document.head.appendChild(scriptTag)
```

also you can set async attribute to true as well.

```
scriptTag.async = true
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the structure of your HTML, but you could do this:

```js
var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0],
    script = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    
button.addEventListener('click', handler, false);

function handler() {
  script.src = 'testing.js';
  console.log(script);
}
```

```html
<button>OK</button>
<script src=""></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative (non-jQuery):

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML += "<script src='testing.js'></script>";
```

`document.getElementsByTagName('body')` gets an array of elements of *body* tag. [0] selects the first (and only, usually) element of that array.

Next, `.innerHTML` accesses the code inside the element (i.e., our only body tag here) and `+=` adds the string (`"<script src='testing.js'></script>"`) after the HTML already in it. And then the script is loaded.

Overall:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function loadScript()  {
                document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML += "<script src='testing.js'></script>";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick='loadScript()'></button>
    </body>
</html>
```